# Blocky SRTM hillshade in QGIS

Tags: qgis, srtm, hillshade

I have downloaded some SRTM topography data, which I've re-projected to a projected coordinate system and displayed as a hillshade. As seen in the attached screenshot, the product looks blocky, with vertical and gridlines visible across the map, even with the resampling set to bilinear or cubic. Is there a way to 'smooth' the hillshading to remove these lines?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your screenshot depicts the classic blocky "herringbone" pattern resulting from applying a *Nearest Neighbor* resampling to raster elevation data.  The solution is to instead apply either a *Bilinear* or *Cubic* resampling method.  The Bilinear method does the least smoothing of the two, and generally solves the blocky pattern.  However, I have come across a few cases where the additional smoothing created by the Cubic method is required to fully remove the pattern.

As a rule of thumb, I **never** use Nearest Neighbor resampling when using raster-based elevation data, and **always** use Nearest Neighbor when using imagery.

You mention that you unsuccessfully tried both Bilinear and Cubic.  Although you didn't state when you applied it, I suspect that you meant **only** when displaying the reprojected SRTM, using *Layer Styling*. However, this may not be sufficient - you must review your entire workflow and identify any tool or process that has a *Resampling* option, making sure to avoid any *Nearest Neighbor* option.  For example, the Warp (Reproject) tool has that option.  Since you reprojected your data, I suspect that's where the error crept in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Stu, changing the resampling method during the re-projection got rid of the "herringbone" pattern.