Slope analysis in northern Nepal
I have just run a slope analysis on data from USGS on elevation in northern Nepal. I ran it on a projection of EPSG:32245 - WGS 72 / UTM zone 45N. Everything ran fine but I am worried about the quality of the output, here is a picture of part of my output:

This is my first time running a slope analysis but it looks off to me? can anyone tell me if this is correct and if not where I might have gone wrong?

Did you reproject the DEM yourself? Make sure there is no Nearest Neighbour/default resampling anywhere in your processing, eg https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107477/what-is-the-source-of-horizontal-and-vertical-striping-in-usgs-dems, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434557/blocky-srtm-hillshade-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462590/what-is-the-hatch-marking-of-my-produced-terrain-slope-raster.

I went through these and tried again with both Bilinear and Cubic processing however, I had the same issue using bilinear and with cubic the slope analysis layer was completely invisible.
